# How can I make div X always maintain the same orientation when inside div's A, B, C, D, etc, where each has a different transform:rotate()?

Tags: css, rotation

[Please see this image to better understand:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0ryp.jpg)

Please note the rabbits inside the circles. In example A, the rabbits rotate along with their parent div's. In example B, they always obey the page orientation.

I would like to achieve B using only CSS, if possible.

PS: Please bear in mind that the rotation of the parent div's is random, as they may come in any rotation.

Comment: if the rabbit is an img element just rotate the image in the opposite direction than the outer element

Comment: show us code and how the *random* part is working

Comment: @fcalderan, I was actually looking for some sort of "absolute position" kind of solution. I understand that what you propose is a solution, but it would require some js coding, no?

Comment: @JoaoM.Campos as someone already asked, how the parent div rotation is done?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, sorry. I can't show you. It's a canvas inside a web app, and it only works when it's already collecting sensitive information. That's why I made the illustrative image.

Comment: @fcalderan, it's a drag and drop functionality on a canvas, which is quite similar to this: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/stateChart.html. When the user drops a box on the canvas, a line connects it to other elements. These are the ones that come rotated. So, when the user connects the boxes, the lines may come in any angle possible. And the element (the rabbit) must always be standing is inside those lines.

Comment: then if you don't know in advance how much the rotation is then you should get this information via javascript

Comment: @fcalderan... I'm afraid so. I didn't want to resource to that, but I think there's no css-only solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply an equal and opposite transform to the rabbits.

```css
.holder {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.holder > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -15px 0 0 -15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Bear in mind that the rotation of the parent div's is random**

Comment: And you can apply that same rotation as [0 - rotation] to the child elements surely?

Comment: am not the OP :) simply showing you the important part of the question